# Custom InfoWindow on Google Map v3 with Shadow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have to add a custom styles Info Window to a Google Map. The rounded border has to go and I have to change the close button.

I've found InfoBox from [Google Maps Utility Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries) which works fine but it doesn't seem to support shadows. Does anybody know of how to achieve this?

Comment: Google changes the way the InfoWindow looks all the time and it's really annoying. You can't rely that any HTML you've inserted will work consistently over time, and the rounded borders disappear and are replaced with square ones.  Soon they'll no doubt go back to rounded.  If you want an info window that does what **you** want, try the [InfoBox, as demonstrated in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7628522/881250).  The InfoBox uses your own HTML to create the pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the Maps API v3 OverlayView class and use getPanes().floatShadow to get a container into which you can insert a shadow image, and getPanes().floatPane to get a container into which can insert your main infowindow container and content.