# Show/hide div when clicked on marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to javascript and no idea where to start digging information how to implement my idea. I want to open a div like a pop-up over the map when a marker is clicked. I have around 15 markers and every marker has different content and images. The pop-up layout will stay the same. I believe making a div is easier than making a infobox, true?

this is my photoshop sketch:
[Sketch](http://cl.ly/image/0s3u2A1g2H2r)

And this is what I have so far:
[Demo](http://shonderdos.nl/demo/)

What should I try, read and investigate?

Comment: an infobox, like the default boxes in google maps, are provided by the API. Those are fairly easy to use.

Comment: do you know about/know how to use html and css?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the info window of google maps
see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow
and customize it's contents.
like in this question: [Google Maps API v3: Custom styles for infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616666/google-maps-api-v3-custom-styles-for-infowindow)

Comment: so 'google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {' will look for the variable marker. But I add my markers true a function like 'function addMarker() {
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({' how do i hook up the listener?

Comment: in the addMarker method? it's all the same listener anyways?
Or refactor your addMarker method, so you can add a function as variable.