# Google Maps API Infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, infobubble

I've got this Google Map (works on my website, can't get it to work in jsfiddle?)

```
jsfiddle.net/9ZcwX/1/
```

I want to use an infobubble instead of the infowindow because I cant style the infowindow at all with css it seems. Everytime I try to add a new infobubble it just crashes the map. Not having much luck with existing questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there were following issues in your fiddle:

- You didn't included google maps javascript file.
- You didn't provided the dimension to the map container which is important for rendering of map.
- You place the DomListener code before the init code and it was executing before the html was loaded and hence the code failed to find the div with the given `ID`

Your code works fine after the modifications.

**Here is the demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/x8dSP/3605/

I didn't modified anything except reodering the code. I placed this code: `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);`

at the end instead of the beginning and added the necessary javascript file.

And added the following CSS:

```
#map_canvas {
     height: 500px;
     width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps K K, do you know what I have to do to swap out the infowindow for a css editable infobubble? Or how to css the infowindow?

Comment: Yes, you can style the infowindow. Refer the solution on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616666/google-maps-api-v3-custom-styles-for-infowindow . Should be easy to implement. I think this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7628522/2000051

Comment: Got it, I looked at that before and had no luck, instead of trying to make my code work with the parts I wanted from that example, I just took my location and styles accross to the one that worked. Cheers!