# google map utility svn down?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using `key draggable zoom` and `markers cluster` libraries from google map utility. I cannot load the source script for these two libraries from this afternoon. It seems all google map utility svn references are down. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the following script urls cover the keydragzoom library (standard and packed versions):

```
https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/keydragzoom/src/keydragzoom.js
https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/keydragzoom/src/keydragzoom_packed.js
```

And the following covers the markerclusterer (standard and compiled):

```
https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/src/markerclusterer.js
https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/src/markerclusterer_compiled.js
```

You'll also need to specify the imagePath option when instantiating your MarkerClusterer to access the images from GitHub:

```
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, { 
    imagePath: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m' 
});
```

The above approach, of specifically setting the imagePath location, is required because the MarkerClusterer library currently still contains (at the 13th of May 2016) the following hard-coded reference to the decommissioned location:

```
MarkerClusterer.prototype.MARKER_CLUSTER_IMAGE_PATH_ =
    'https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/' +
    'images/m';
```

In production, the above urls (with the cdn prefix) should be used as they have [no traffic limits or throttling and the files are served via a super fast global CDN](https://rawgit.com/).  However please bear in mind that, as a free service, it offers [no uptime or support guarantees](https://github.com/rgrove/rawgit/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#i-need-guaranteed-100-uptime-should-i-use-cdnrawgitcom).

Accessing files hosted from Git is covered in more detail in the following SO answer:

[Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049842/1301937)

Comment: Good solutions! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

See this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171426/google-maps-api-v3-infobox-js-removed). The google maps utility library is being moved to [github](http://googlemaps.github.io/libraries.html). You can still [browse the code](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js), but you cannot checkout svn.

Comment: Good reference and explain! Thanks!