# My maplabels stopped working. I now get the message below in all my programs

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

`new MapLabel` used to work in all my programs but this does not work any more:

```
var mapLabelA = new MapLabel(
    {
        text: ' From Wilkes or Henlow** ',
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.796600, -97.196000),
        map: map,
        fontSize: 13,
        align: 'right'
    }
);
```

Why would my maplabels stop working?

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
PT59AM2.html:1039 Uncaught ReferenceError: MapLabel is not defined
util.js:222 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
util.js:222 Google Maps API warning: InvalidKey https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key
```

Comment: So you got an error message. What is your question?

Comment: Why would my maplabels stop working ?

Comment: Put that into the question proper by [edit]ing it. Also, include more context. Ideally provide a [mcve].

Comment: var mapLabelA = new MapLabel({
          text: ' From Wilkes or Henlow** ',
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.796600, -97.196000),
          map: map,
          fontSize: 13,
          align: 'right'
          
        });

Comment: new MapLabel used to work in all my programs but this does not work anymore

Comment: MapLabel is a thirt party library and you are probably including it from google svn. Sources from svn have been recently moved to git. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171426/google-maps-api-v3-infobox-js-removed

Answer (score 0):

Google deleted maplabel.js from their servers.  Find another copy or link to it locally.