# google maps api moved to git hub -- where?

Tags: google-maps, github-api

It seems the Google maps api has moved to github but I can't find it there.  What URL do I use to replace the line of code below?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?    key=myapikeyhere&callback=initMap&signed_in=true" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't approve what you say, my project at work uses the same url.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/adding-a-google-map?hl=de#introduction

There you can find a basic tutorial.

Comment: I read at the link below " the library is being moved to Github"
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171426/google-maps-api-v3-infobox-js-removed