# MarkerManager for google maps v2 is not loading

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svn, google-maps-api-2

I'm using google maps v2 (GMap2) for desktop web development and MarkerManager from this link:
http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/release/src/markermanager.js

```
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=mykey" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/release/src/markermanager.js"></script>
```

few days ago I link gives error and markermanager.js is not found. 
Where can I get it for google maps v2?

note:
I was searching on google and all I found is markermanager.js for google maps v3 while I want it for google maps v2 for now.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Related question: [Google Maps API V3 Infobox.js removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171426/google-maps-api-v3-infobox-js-removed)

Google code is [shut down per the announcement](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html)

> **Bidding farewell to Google Code**
>
> Thursday, March 12, 2015
>
> - January 25, 2016 - The project hosting service is closed. You will be able to download a tarball of project source, issues, and wikis. These tarballs will be available throughout the rest of 2016.

[post on the google blog](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html).

You can still [access the source of the repository containing the v2 version of the MarkerManager](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/), you just can't use the code from there, you need to download it and either create a github project or put it on your server.

[download link for source archive](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-source/v2/code.google.com/gmaps-utility-library-dev/source-archive.zip)