# Google Maps RouteBoxer API missing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been using this API for several years now and it's worked as recently as March or April of this year.  Now, I'm getting a 404 error from:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/src/RouteBoxer.js

Has this API been deprecated?

Thanks!

Comment: duplicate of [Google Maps API V3 Infobox.js removed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171426/google-maps-api-v3-infobox-js-removed)

Comment: [excuse]That post doesn't reference the api I was using/searching, so I didn't see it.[/excuse]  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That link stopped working. You can find the implementation here
https://github.com/denissellu/routeboxer/blob/master/src/RouteBoxer.js

or here
https://github.com/nmccready/google-maps-utility-library-v3-keydragzoom

Or you can use some other similar solutions, like **Leaflet RouteBoxer** which you can find here https://github.com/StephanGeorg/leaflet-routeboxer

Comment: Thanks! ("Votes cast by members with less than 15 rep are recorded, but do not affect post score"  -  :sad_face:)

Comment: Your second link is dead as well.