# Google Maps GMSMarker infoWindow frame

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

In iOS, is there any way to get the frame or location of the GMSMarker infoWindow that pops up? I have created my own custom view for the infoWindow and it all works, but I want to be able to get the location of that infoWindow when the user taps on it. I am implementing the didTapInfoWindowOfMarker delegate method, but cannot find any object that tells me what the location of that infoWindow is. I have tried creating the infoWindow as global to the class, and in the didTapInfoWindowOfMarker method look at the frame, but it always shows up as (0,0,200,70). The size is right but the origin is not. I have searched Google, and I have not been able to find anything on this.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Maps API v3: Custom styles for infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616666/google-maps-api-v3-custom-styles-for-infowindow)

I'm used css or if click a marker, I start a jquery style function in listener.