# Unique ng-model for forms embedded in info window (Google Maps API)

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

On every click on the google map, I'm creating a marker and each marker has an info window which contains a form. But the form on all info windows ends up having the same text which isn't what I want. How do I create different forms with different text ?

Here is my code :

Html

```
 <ng-map center="[40.74, -74.18]"  map-type-control-options="{style:'HORIZONTAL_BAR', position:'BOTTOM_CENTER'}" zoom="3" style="height:30em;" on-click="addNewMarker(event)">
```

Javascript :

```
 $scope.all_forms = [];
 $scope.addNewMarker = function(e)
 {
     var form = '<div id="form_canvasform"  >' +
                  '<form name="form_canvas">' +
                  '<textarea class="form-control" required placeholder="Your Text..." ng-model="mk[$scope.all_forms.length].text">{{all_forms}}</textarea><br/>' +
                  '<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="uploadNewImageMap()" ng-model="mkimage" id="markerJs">Upload Image</button>' +
                   '<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="uploadNewVideoMap()" ng-model="mkvideo" id="markerJs3">Upload Video</button><br/>' +
                  '</form>' +
                 '</div>';

    var form_compiled = $compile(form)($scope);

    $scope.all_forms.push(form_compiled);


     all_infoWindow[markerCounter] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:$scope.all_forms[$scope.markerCounter][0]}); 
     all_markers[markerCounter] = new google.maps.Marker({position: e.latLng, map: map, draggable:true});

     infoWindow.open(map,marker); // not infoWindow.open(app,marker);

     google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow,'closeclick',function(){
        marker.setMap(null);
     });

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'position_changed', function() {
        if(infoWindow.getMap()){
          infoWindow.open(map,this);
        }
      });
      $scope.markerCounter += 1;
   }
```

Image :

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the documentation, [**`InfoWindow`**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) has very limited options if you want to customize it specially setting its content.

I would suggest that you use `infobox` instead of `infowindow`.

As mentioned in this [GitHub](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/infobox) post:

> An InfoBox behaves like a `google.maps.InfoWindow`, but it supports several additional properties for advanced styling.

With more properties as compared with options used in `infowindow`, styling the contents or the entire window is easier by simply passing a few parameters.

Please check the given [GitHub post](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/infobox) for sample implementation codes.

Lastly, solutions given in this SO post - [Google Maps API v3: Custom styles for infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616666/google-maps-api-v3-custom-styles-for-infowindow) might be of help too.